# Указатель на класс

Tags: objective-c

Подскажите, есть ли разница между

```
NSString *MyString =@"Hello World";
```

и

```
 NSString MyString =@"Hello World";
```

Знаю, что указатель - это тип данных, в котором сохраняется адрес в памяти. Но зачем он нужен? Адрес до чего?

Comment: Разница в том, что второй вариант не скомпилируется. Рассмотрите более детально язык Си, который является базисом для objc, вам все станет понятно.

Comment: Для начала стоит разобраться в том, что такое указатель, что такое объект, что такое класс, и чем они отличаются. Понять разницу между динамической, автоматической и статической памятью. Понять, как устроены классы в objective-c. До этого момента проще запомнить, что второй вариант просто неправильный, потому что это истина свыше.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Указатель на объект указывает на первую ячейку памяти, в которой хранится объект.
Не существует указателей на класс.

Comment: В отличие от, например, си++, в objective-c класс - это такой же объект, как и экземпляр класса. А если совсем строго на это все посмотреть, то ни объекты, ни классы в objective-c не являются классами в том виде, в котором они есть в c++. Подробнее можно узнать поискав по ключевым словам "objective c runtime". Хотя Гошке про это в любом случае знать рановато ;)

Comment: @dieworld если начать прыгать с одного уровня абстракции на другой, то в objective-c класс это не объект, это структура c :)